# iPhone: Good idea to dealloc and rellocate UI items when switching views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Suppose I have 2 views. In the first view, I allocate memory to displaying many UI components such as an UILabel, UIImages, etc.

Suppose the user navigates to the next view (via UINavigationController)

Is it OK to deallocate memory assigned to displaying UI components in the first view and then initialize them again once the user goes back to the first view (in viewFirstLoad or the appropriate function)?

It seems to me if you don't do this, then memory will keep on increasing the longer the user uses your app in that particular session.

Is this not allowed? frowned upon? impossible?

Comment: I think you can, but I would rather not deallocate UI components between navigations. However if you have a big data and you can access it easily then I probably deallocate/allocate it between views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly normal and in fact, that functionality is built in standard UIViewController - when controller is not displayed its view may be released from memory and you can release all its subviews (e.g. retained through IBOutlet references) in controller's `-viewDidUnload` method.

When controller needs to display again it reloads its view again.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Generally, the rule of thumb is that you should free objects that you don't need. If your view is just a view, then yes, I'd release it and all of its subviews. If your view has data that was obtained through a lengthy retrieval process (e.g. a web service call), I'd probably hold onto the data somewhere so that I don't have to go back out and retrieve it when the user goes back to the first view.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a little: Apple recommends you display data specific to a view in it's -viewDidLoad method, such as setting text on labels. Then, in -viewDidUnload you should release (or nil outlets of) the view objects you setup in -viewDidLoad. It's critical you implement -viewDidLoad, as the base UIViewController code checks that it's subclass actually implements -viewDidLoad before it assumes it can unload the view (and therefore call -viewDidUnload). Failing to implement -viewDidLoad results in the controller thinking it can't recreate your view at a later time, and so it doesn't unload the view from memory. A developer I know experienced this same problem, took forever to track down.